# nWire equivalent for Netbeans?

Tags: ide, netbeans, nwire

I stumbled upon nWire and have to say it looks very promising for me.

I wonder if there is a nWire equivalent for Netbeans?

I hope there is!

Comment: For those not familiar with nWire: http://www.nwiresoftware.com/

Comment: I couldn't find a nWire equivlant for NetBeans, but I found some other tools that are similar and might help you get the same effect.  See this other post for some good options (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235513/php-call-graph-utility)